# initialising list with given length and content

Tags: r, data-structures

Say that I want to create a list of length `2`, and fill each slice with the sequence `1:3` directly. I know that creating a list with pre-specified length can be done as

`l <- vector("list", length = 2)`

and all slices will be filled with `NULL`.

one way I've found is to use `lapply`:

`lapply(l, function(x) x=1:3)`

which will do it:

```
> l <- vector("list", length = 2)     
> lapply(l, function(x) x=1:3)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

But is there a way to do it straight away?

Comment: you don't need to initialise your list, `lapply(1:2, function(x) 1:3)` works the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an option with `replicate`

```
replicate(2, 1:3, simplify = FALSE)
#[[1]]
#[1] 1 2 3

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 3
```

---

Or apply `rep` on a `list`

```
rep(list(1:3), 2)
```

Comment: or lapply(1:2, function(x) x=1:3)